# Syncing a JTable with ArrayList of Objects values in Java

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable

My program has a JTable which displays information about a student. e.g.

```
Columns contain: "Name", "Surname", "Age", "Year"
```

I also have an Object class for students as follow:

```
public class Student {
    private final String name;
    private final String surname;
    private final int age;
    private int year;

    public Student(String name, String surname, int age, int year) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return this.surname;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return this.year;
    }

    public void setYear(int i) {
        this.year = i;
    }
}
```

I have a StudentManager below:

```
public class StudentManager {
    private static ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public static void addStudent(Student obj) {
        this.students.add(obj);
    }

    public static void removeStudent(Student obj) {
        this.students.remove(obj);
    }

    public static Student getStudentByName(String n) {
        for(Student s : this.students) {
            if(s.getName() == n)
                return s;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

What i want to know:

I want it so that when i change a value in the student class object the JTable will update with the new information.

I also want the JTable to remove the row of a student if I was to remove a Student class object from my ArrayList.

Also the same with adding a Student, I want it to add a row to the JTable with the students Name, Surname, Age and Year.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is basically the hole bottom paragraph, under "What i want to know:"

Comment: This is  Q&A site. You either ask questions to concrete problems or you won't get sensible responses. From your post it seems that you want us to program for you which will not happen.

Comment: I realise this, and no I do not want you to program it for me, I just wrote it like that because I wasn't sure about how it may work so I tried writing what I want to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `StudentTableModel` (which extends [`AbstractTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html)) that will supply data for the JTable and when some change occures it will fire updates (`fire*` methods).

Next, the `StudentTableModel` needs to know that some change occured. I would use [`PropertyChangeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html) for that. See [`PropertyChangeSupport`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html) to see how it is used.

Basically, your `StudentTableModel` will listen to changes from `StudentManager` and each `Student` and it will propagate the updates to `JTable`.

Alternative ways:

- You can use `Observable`/`Observer` instead of `PropertyChangeListener`
- You can merge functionality of `StudentTableModel` and `StudentManager`